# is it possible to create a table of contents in react from html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a document and would like to create a table of contents

```
<h1>heading 1</h1>
<section>content</section>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<section>content</section>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
<section>content</section>
<h3>heading 3</h2>
<section>content</section>
<h2>heading 2</h2>
```

so all the h2 and h3 should be nested in h1 and all h3 nested in h2.
I can do this in javascript where i work with DOM Nodes but cannot work around a way in react as it discourages dom manipulation

Comment: You can probably parse the html document as a string, then render as JSX.
There are a bunch of npm libraries that can do it for you.

Comment: ok. i thought of looping through the document as a string and retrieving h1 tags buth thought it would be slow of the document is long.

Comment: It can be faster than you think. Can you elaborate on what you mean by React discouraging DOM manipulation.

Comment: what I mean is that react favors updating the state when adding elements to its virtual DOM over using  UseRef.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

const regex = new RegExp(`(?<=<h\\d>)(.*?)(?=<)`,'g')
```

Ok. what i did was to use `renderToStaticMarkup` and regex to retrieve heading tags.

`ReactHtmlParser` is used to render html string to JSX. So the idea is to convert between an html string and JSX format.

Answer (score 2):

In React, you should create a reference to the node and call `nodeRef.current.querySelectorAll("h2,h3,h4,h5,h6")` to retrieve the headings in that node. This would be the React way to get the needed data. You are not manipulating the DOM, just grabbing the containing nodes. If you are using a hooks compatible version of react, I recommend [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) as the simplest way to reference the container node.

Once you have that, you can create a tree for your node data, which is mainly necessary if you want to display it in a nested [unordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) for your table of contents.

I created a hook for exactly that. You can [check out the source for ideas](https://github.com/kbrock84/use-page-headings-tree/tree/master) or use the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-page-headings-tree).

This hook only generates the data needed for the table of contents, but the README has a [simple example using recursion](https://github.com/kbrock84/use-page-headings-tree/blob/master/README.md#example-usage) for how to render it. [Here's the live example on github pages](https://kbrock84.github.io/use-page-headings-tree/)

The algorithm to generate the tree is not simple enough to for a stack overflow response. Let me know if you find a simpler way!

Comment: i used regex,  renderToStaticMarkup and ReactHtmlParser. I use renderToStaticMarkup t covert html to string, regex to identfy heading tags from converted string and ReactHtmlParser to convert an html string to JSX